# Ubuntu 20.04 no internet on wifi through dns

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, dns

Yesterday I set up a raspberry pi based pihole dns and got the connection working fine on my laptop and phone. Today, on wake, my laptop (Ubuntu 20.04 kde plasma, HP 14z-fq000, AMD 3020e, WiFi card rtl8821ce 802.11ac)is unable to access the wider internet through the dns. The wifi is listed as, connected (limited connectivity), and I have access to the local network such as the pihole (via ssh) and my phone, I cannot get it to connect to the wider internet though.
Nslookups of various sites all return non - authoritative answers but no errors.
I have no such issues on my phone.

The pihole (via ssh) is able to run update commands so has internet access.

This has happened before with this machine (the limited connectivity on wake issue, but prior to having the dns set up) but previously was always fixed with a reboot.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like a DHCP issue - can you check the IP address assigned to the laptop?

Comment: Yes, in terminal it's listed as ending in 154, the same address I have as the address in the network settings next to the network mask under DHCP. The dns server ends in 164.

Comment: My mistake, the laptop ip is xxx.xxx.1.54 and then the dns is 1.164 but they're still both copied correctly into the dns settings

Comment: I suspect either the laptop network routes are incorrect, or DNS failures are the problem.  To check the latter, try setting DNS on the laptop to `1.1.1.1` or another well-known DNS server and see if the problem is eliminated.  Fixing routing could be more involved - but the laptop should be getting the right "gateway" configured via DHCP (or try hard-coding it to see if that works).

Comment: The IP address assignment of the laptop being in DNS is a nice-to-have; DNS is only used to do name-to-ip translation in most cases, and reaching the internet from your laptop, nothing in the network is using the laptop name to do a DNS lookup, unless something is highly unusual in the setup.

Comment: Ok, using the 1.1.1.1 dns and a reboot the internet access returned, so that may be the problem. Do you have any suggestions on how I can keep the dns server im trying to use active without having the internet access cut off on wake?